# How can I track internet upload/download on linux while ignoring local traffic?

Tags: linux, nfs, statistics

I have two Linux boxes connected to a router and the router is connected to a modem. The Linux computers share file systems via NFS.  I want to track internet usage upload and download values, ignoring the local (nfs/ssh) traffic.  I'd prefer to pull these values from `/proc`.  Looking for a minimal proccessing power solution.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track internet traffic as a whole, the only way is from the router not the individual machines.

Check if your router supports SNMP. If it does you can get an snmp client for Linux on one of the PCs to monitor the network usage of the WAN interface on the router (that's the external interface) which will show you the total traffic in/out of the Internet.

Anything else will be complex since you would need to filter out any local traffic from the machines & the router.

Comment: I only care about traffic to/from internet from the one box.

Comment: But that box is connected to the LAN not direct to the Internet so other traffic is present. To do more requires a more sophisticated network monitor that can filter out all but the traffic you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You can add two rules to iptables to segment out the packets going to and from the internet. Note you will have to adapt them to your system and network settings. I'm assuming network interface name **eth1** and **192.168.0.0/24**.

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i eth0 ! -s 192.168.0.0/24
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -o eth0 ! -d 192.168.0.0/24
```

Then you can see the bandwidth usage like this:

```
# iptables -nvx -L INPUT
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 542 packets, 63745 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   35  4533            all  --  eth0   *       ! 192.169.0.0/24     0.0.0.0/0
# iptables -nvx -L OUTPUT
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 247 packets, 27847 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   48  4724            all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            ! 192.168.0.0/24
```